# Plot all columns from dataframe without having to define them in Plotly

Tags: plot, automation, plotly, multiple-columns

I would like to plot in Plotly all columns from dataframe without having to define them.

The required is the same functionality in Plotly as here in matplotlib.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['15','21','30'],
    'M': ['12','24','31'],
    'I': ['28','32','10']})


%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df=df.astype(float)
df.plot()
```

Here is my code for Plotly, but as I said, I have no idea how to plot all the columns automatically. The once I have noticed is also, that in Plotly the X-axis needs to be defined, but with this restriction I can live.

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os

# data

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['1','2','3'],
    'A': ['15','21','30'],
    'M': ['12','24','31'],
    'I': ['28','32','10']})

df_long=pd.melt(df , id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['A', 'M' , 'I'])

fig = px.line(df_long, x='ID', y='value', color='variable')
fig.show()
```

How can I define how to plot in Plotly all the columns automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i have found the solution to my problem:

```
df_long=pd.melt(df , id_vars=['ID'])
```

instead of:

```
df_long=pd.melt(df , id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['A', 'M' , 'I'])
```

Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars.